# I want to move to another view controller after a dispatch_async task

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I am trying to call a method from another view controller by creating an object in the present view controller. I am using dispatch_async block to do that with a serial queue.The next task of the serial queue must be the navigation to another controller (By the way it is the same controller I used the first task method from). But the serial queue is executing 2nd task even before fetching the data from 1st task. So the condition in the 2nd task fails and navigation won't happen. Please help me.

I saw many answers to use serial queue to get the job done but I know that to change user interface we have to be on main thread. So, is that why controller doesn't change? is there a way to create a serial queue on main thread? Or is it always on different thread? Any other solution to my problem is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    dispatch_queue_t serialQueue=dispatch_queue_create("***", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^
    {
        NSLog(@"first async");
        [discoveryNewsObject callDiscoveryNewsRequest];
        NSLog(@"first async complete");
    });

    dispatch_async(serialQueue(), ^
    {
       NSLog(@"second async");
       if ([NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.getNewsArray[0]].count==[NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.postImageDimensionsArray].count && [NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.getNewsArray[0]].count!=0)
    {
        NSLog(@"counts are equal");

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DiscoverySegue" sender:self];
    }
    NSLog(@"second async complete");
});
```

Comment: Why are you perform this kind of step in queue? You can by simple method go to the another view controller.

Comment: so you want to wait both async closure to finish then only move to next viewcontroller?

Comment: u want me to copy the method from another view controller to here and try it?? Saurabh

Comment: yes. Tj3n. I want the first task to be completed before moving to another controller.

Comment: You should post the `callDiscoveryNewsRequest ` function, it probably need a completion block to execute code after it finish requesting

Comment: No it doesn't. But there is a method inside that has a completion block. Is that the issue?? And do the control return before executing the completion block of a method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait for both block completed after that you want to perform segue

try this code

```
  dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^
                   {
                       NSLog(@"first async");
                       [discoveryNewsObject callDiscoveryNewsRequest];
                       NSLog(@"first async complete");
                       dispatch_group_leave(group);
                   });
    dispatch_group_enter(group);

    dispatch_async(serialQueue(), ^
                   {
                       NSLog(@"second async");
                       if ([NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.getNewsArray[0]].count==[NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.postImageDimensionsArray].count && [NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.getNewsArray[0]].count!=0)
                       {
                           NSLog(@"counts are equal");

                       }
                       NSLog(@"second async complete");
                       dispatch_group_leave(group);

                   });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DiscoverySegue" sender:self];

    })
```

---

### EDIT

---

as you observe that  `[discoveryNewsObject callDiscoveryNewsRequest];`
need some time to return

your method edit for `callDisCoveryNewRequest` is

```
- (void) callDisCoveryNewRequestWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)())block;
```

and after your fetch completed return `block()`
 and do `dispatch_group_leave(group);` on completion block of  `callDisCoveryNewRequestWithCompletionBlock`

Hope it helps

Comment: call `dispatch_group_leave(group)` right after `callDiscoveryNewsRequest ` wont have any effect without a completion handler i think, because `callDiscoveryNewsRequest` is async (probably?) then it will just skip the process and leave the group rightaway

Comment: ya  `[discoveryNewsObject callDiscoveryNewsRequest];` need block operation and he should implement block there and leave on success or failure of that block

Comment: mike alter- I didn't notice at first because of less data fetching, but when data is high that actually takes some seconds to fetch the control is still moving to the other controller before the fetching happens.. Is there any other way to achieve what i want??